# How to generate an unique number for every 180 days in a list of objects

Tags: c#, datetime

So I have objects with an `int` and a `DateTime` that I must insert in a `list`.
The date is known, but the int must be unique for every 180 days of the date.

If the dates are: , the number for every 180 should be

01.01.2019 - 1,

01.03.2019 - 2,

01.05.2019 - 3,

02.05.2019 - 4,

02.07.2019 - 1, (because 180 passed since 01.01.2019, so it can be 1 again)

03.07.2019 - 5,
etc..

Comment: Does it have to be an integer? If not, you could use a GUID `Guid.NewGuid();`

Comment: You want a number from 1 incrementing with each date, until 180 days have passed, then reset this to 1 and continue? Can you share a bit of code and explain where you are stuck? Like, is this object a class? Can you set its `int` value after construction? Are you stuck with the resetting the counter in a loop? Or the time span?

Comment: `(endDate - startDate).TotalDays % 180`? What have you tried?

Comment: These are mm.dd.yyyy right?

Answer (score 0):

Given an `IndexedDate` class to put these in, and some dates, `IEnumerable<DateTime> dates`, you can walk through them all keeping track of the `current` start date:

```
    private static List<IndexedDate> IndexTheDates(IEnumerable<DateTime> dates)
    {
        List<IndexedDate> ret = new List<IndexedDate>();
        if (!dates.Any())
            return ret;
        var current = dates.First();
        int index = 1;
        foreach(var date in dates)
        {
            ret.Add(new IndexedDate(date, index++));
            if (date >= current + TimeSpan.FromDays(180))
            {
                current = date;
                index = 1;
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the dates in your list are unique, and you don't care about the numbers being sequential starting with one, then you can use this function:

```
public int GetDateId(DateTime date)
{
    return (int)TimeSpan.FromTicks(date.Ticks).TotalDays % 180;
}
```

It transforms the given date to days count and divides the count by 180. The remainder is a unique number per date.